# How does Jagadguru Ramanandacharya explain the most lovable moment of Shri Sita Ram?

Tags: rama, sita, ramnandacharya, ramanand, vaishnav

How does Jagadguru Ramanandacharya explain the most lovable moment of Shri Sita Ram? In which Book he has written that?

Answer (score 1):

**सीतानाथ समारम्भां रामानन्दार्य मध्यमाम्।
अस्मदाचार्य पर्यन्तां वन्दे श्रीगुरू परम्पराम् ।।**

[image]

Ānand Bhāshyakār Śrīmad Jagadguru Rāmānandāchārya was Incarnation of the most sweetest lord Rajdulāre Śrī Raghunandan ( रामानन्दः स्वयं रामः प्रादुर्भूतो महीतले ), he appeared in Kali-Yuga in 1299.

Śrī Ānand Bhāshyakār Bhagwān has described a very lovable moment of Lord Śrī SītāRām in his very initial Shlokā of Śrīmad Vāishnav Matābja Bhāskaraḥ (code book of a Vaishnava). Śrī Ānand Bhāshyakār Bhagwān writes;

> श्रीमन्तं श्रुतिवेद्यमद्भुतगुणग्रामाग्यरत्नाकरं प्रेयः
> स्वेक्षणसंसुलज्जितमहीजाताक्षिकोणेक्षितम् ।
> भक्ताशेषमनोभिवाञ्छितचतुर्वर्गप्रदं स्वद्रुमं रामं स्मेरमुखाम्बुजं
> शुचिमहानीलाश्मकान्तिं भजे ॥ 1 ॥

https://youtu.be/IR3wBXjGHDY

Word-Meaning

śrutivedyam = knowable through the veda’s ; adbhutagunagrāmāgrya ratnākaram = ocean of gem-like supernatural attributes ; preyaḥ svekṣanasamsulajjita mahījātākṣikonekṣitam = viewed by the glancing angle of her modest beloved, daughter of the Earth, Sitaji ; bhaktäśeṣamanobhiväñch- itacaturvargapradaṁ svardrumaṁ = like a Kalpataru in providing dharma, artha, kāma, mokṣādi i.e. all the desired puruṣārtha to all devotees; smeramukhambujam = face blooming like a lotus; śucimahānīlāśmakäntim = splendour is like a holy sapphire; śrīmantam = śrīmāna i.e. with Sītāji; Rāmam = to ŚrīRāma; bhaje= (I) worship.

Knowable through the Veda-s, ocean of collections of gem-like supernatural attributes, viewed by the glancing angle of her modest beloved, daughter of the Earth (Sītāji) like a Kalpataru in providing dharma, artha, kama, mokşa etc., i.e. all the desired puruṣārtha to all devotees, face blooming like a lotus and whose splendour is like a holy sapphire, I (Rāmānandācārya), worship to that śrīmān (śrī i.e. with Sītāji) Rāmaji.

[image]

No one is like my Śrī Ānand Kand Awadh Dulare Pran Jeevan Dhan Siya Harshvardhan Śrī Raghunandan

Please Chant SitaRam SitaRam SitaRam

Hail to Srimad Tulsidās Ji Maharāj

Hail to Ānand Bhāshyakār Śrīmad Jagādgurü Ramānandacharya